# How do I list an AJAX post in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inputvalores.php",
    data: {
        id: id,
        nomeproduto: nomeproduto,
        tec: tec,
        tipi: tipi,
        quantProduto: quantProduto,
        valorAduaneiro: valorAduaneiro,
        breadzin: breadzin
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#resposta").html(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And this is my PHP code `inputvalores.php`:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nomeproduto = $_POST['nomeproduto'];
    $tec = $_POST['tec'];
    $tipi = $_POST['tipi'];
    $quantProduto = $_POST['quantProduto'];
    $valorAduaneiro = $_POST['valorAduaneiro'];
    $breadzin = $_POST['breadzin'];

    echo '<div>'.$id.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="breadcrumbs">'.$breadzin.'</div>';
    echo '<li class="produto">';
    echo '<div class="ordem">'.$id.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="nomedoproduto">'.$nomeproduto.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="quantidade">'.$quantProduto.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="botoes"><button class="editar">Editar</button>
          <button class="excluir">Excluir</button></div>';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

But if I do a new POST in AJAX it overwrites this item. How do I get them listed?

I tried a bunch of stringify and things like that but I'm a newbie in AJAX, PHP or even JQUERY and Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try `$("#resposta").append(data);`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this is a PHP related problem? Also, be warned that your script is open for XSS injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed

```
 $("#resposta").html(data);
```

to

```
 $("#resposta").append(data);
```

Thank you, very much @Dhaval Purohit